# Changing font size into an AlertDialog

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog, font-size

I am trying to put some loooong text into an AlertDialog.
The only issue the default font size that is really too big, so I want to make it smaller.

Here are all the workaround I tried and their issues.

**Workaround 1)** Using a TextView  and myView.setTextSize(12);

```
final TextView myView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
myView.setText(myLongText);
myView.setTextSize(12);
final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
.setTitle(myTitle)
.setView(myView)
.create();
```

*Issues*: Layout is not scrolling

**Workaround 2)** making TextView scrollable.

```
message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

*Issues*: Layout is scrolling, bute there is no "inertia" (don't know how to call that.. But I guess you understand.)

**Workaround 3)** Using a Scrollview.

That's what I am going to try, but I cannot believe there are no easier solutions...

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can actually get access to the message's `TextView` pretty easily, and then change it's size. I tested with a bigger size, but you could use whatever size you want. The text will scroll nicely as it already does. The view's `id` is `android.R.id.message`

```
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Hello world").show();
    TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
```

This is probably a cleaner solution, though I'm not sure if there's a risk that the `TextView` could be `null` or not.

Comment: well, the text textView object does seem to be null

Comment: You must call setMessage() when building the dialog, otherwise there would be no message textview in the first place.

Comment: Actually you have to call `show()` too,  otherwise there's no TextView. If you want to scale the buttons as well, use `android.R.id.button1` etc

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18767270/2914140 to understand why textView can be null.

Comment: How to change that font if one has only `AlertDialog.Builder` object?

Comment: What about the size of the `Title` now (`android.R.id.message` is for message field of the `AlertDialog`). What id is allocated for the `Title`?

Answer (score 28):

I am using the following code to change the title and message text for AlertDialog…

```java
final int alertTitle = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
setTitleFont((TextView) dlg.findViewById(alertTitle));
setBodyFont((TextView) dlg.findViewById(android.R.id.message));
```

… making sure that I check for `null` in my `setTitleFont` and `setBodyFont` methods.

Comment: This worked for getting the title View (thanks!), but once I got it I could only set two fonts: the standard font, and a tiny font (with 11.0 for the value).

Comment: This worked for me to set a font from assets folder to the title of the alert box. Good one!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using this I was able to change the title font size as follows:

int alertTitle = context.getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
View title = dialog.findViewById(alertTitle);
if (title != null && title instanceof TextView) {
  ((TextView) title).setTextSize(14);
}

Comment: what is the difference between these two methods of getting reference to the id. Why is there no android.R.id.alertTitle?

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work anymore with the recent updates.  findViewById() always returns null.  :-(

Comment: If you're using `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`, you have to use  `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.alertTitle` otherwise use `android.R.id.title`

Comment: No more working in 2020. Using custom style is the only way to workout.

Answer (score 9):

For Buttons:

```java
  final AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainScreen)
      .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
      .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).create();

  ad.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
      @Override
      public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
          int textSize = (int) Helper.getDimen(mainScreen, R.dimen.textSize12);
          ad.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextSize(textSize);
          ad.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextSize(textSize);
      }

  });

  ad.show();
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't getting any upvotes. It may not be an answer to the OP's direct question but as soon as you make the message bigger/smaller, you'll may well want to make the button text bigger/smaller. This seems like a nice, natural (alright, at least javascript-y) way to accomplish the task if it has to be done at runtime anyway.

I combined this with the accepted good answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6563075/165164) and put those two lines inside the listener. Also, didn't bother with the getDimen call, just set a size.

Don't forget to declare ad final!

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution... you need to create the scroll container, then add the TextView inside the ScrollView just as you would in the XML layout.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
String str = getString(R.string.upgrade_notes); 
final ScrollView s_view = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
final TextView t_view = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
t_view.setText(str);
t_view.setTextSize(14);     
s_view.addView(t_view);
alertDialog.setTitle("Upgrade notes!");
alertDialog.setView(s_view);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in 2020. I have tested this in Android 10

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.YourStyle) //Style is only needed if you want to customize look&feel
            .setTitle(R.string.title)
            .setMessage(R.string.message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, null);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(dialog -> {
        //The following is to style dialog message
        TextView message = alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        if (message != null) {
            message.setTextSize(12);
            message.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.yellow));
        }
        //The following is to style dialog title. Note that id is alertTitle
        TextView title = alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.alertTitle);
        if (title != null) {
            title.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.black));
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using SpannableStringBuilder instead of a string.

http://www.android--tutorials.com/2016/10/android-change-alertdialog-title-text_21.html

Answer (score -1):

```
               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
                AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Your Title");
                builder.setMessage("Your Message");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // Your Positive Function
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // Your Negative Function
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
```