# Change fontsize for ListView in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-listview, font-size, android-alertdialog

I have a simple AlertDialog that displays different titles, but some are too long so they are truncated in the dialog. How can I adjust the fontsize of the text of the entire ListView so that it fits the screen?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyMaps.this);
builder.setTitle("Titles");
builder.setItems(m_Titles, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
  {
      dialog.dismiss();
      /// DO SOME ON CLICK STUFF
  }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

A [similar question exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562924/changing-font-size-into-an-alertdialog/6563075#6563075), but that's about explaining how to change the size of a TextView.

Answer (score -1):

you can create custom dialog using XML file for layout..

here is simple example for it  [Example's Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)