# How to set Alert text size in alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

The alert message by default is too big for specific devices with little screens and I want to set it to a custom dp

My alert is something like this

```
OnClickListener addNewItemListener = new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            MyActivity.this);

                    LinearLayout myLayout= new LinearLayout(MyActivity.this);
                    myLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    alert.setTitle(R.string.add_title);
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.add_message);

                    final TextView t1 = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
                    t1.setText("Name");
                    final EditText input1 = new EditText(MyActivity.this);
                    myLayout.addView(t1);
                    myLayout.addView(input1);
                    alert.setView(myLayout);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.cancel,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                }
                            });
                    alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                    try {
                                        ....
                                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                                        Alerts.DatiErrati(MyActivity.this);
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                    alert.show();
                }
            };
```

How could I set the text size of the alert message?

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT 2:**

This is the best method you can go with

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Record and Images will be deleted?")
        .setTitle("MyTitle")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id)
                            {

                                dialog.cancel();
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id)
                            {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
```

You can use the following to get bigger text only

```
  alert.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<Big>"+getString(R.string.add_message)+"</Big>"));
```

**Note:** you can use more **big's** for more bigger text

Comment: I have yet tried this solution but the problem is that there is no margins between the TextView with the message and the other elemets of the Alert

Comment: you can create a dialog.xml for this and inflate this to your view like this

Comment: Is there no way to do this without inflate an xml?

Comment: @AndreaF take your answer change the text size  as per your need

Comment: @AndreaF see the updated answer it will solve your problem and if it helps then accept it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Hello world").show();
TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
textView.setTextSize(40);
```

Comment: unfortunately, `textView.setTextSize(40);` fails with a `NPE`. The `TextView`'s id apparently is **not** `android.R.id.message`. Further advice?

Comment: Try to follow this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455919/material-design-not-styling-alert-dialogs
Explaining how to style your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code to control alertDialog**

```
  AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("title")
                    .setMessage("message")
                    .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.yes), (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), (dialogInterface, i) -> dialogInterface.dismiss())


            try {

//                          /Modify Determine the font size of the Cancel button
//                builder.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextSize(26);
//                builder.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextSize(26);

                // Get the mAlert object
                Field mAlert = AlertDialog.class.getDeclaredField("mAlert");
                mAlert.setAccessible(true);
                Object mAlertController = mAlert.get(builder);

                // Get mTitleView and set the size of the color
                Field mTitle = mAlertController.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleView");
                mTitle.setAccessible(true);
                TextView mTitleView = (TextView) mTitle.get(mAlertController);
                mTitleView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._13sdp));
                mTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_black));
                mTitleView.setLineSpacing(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8f, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), 1.0f);
                mTitleView.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
                mTitleView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);

                // Get mMessageView and set the size of the color
                Field mMessage = mAlertController.getClass().getDeclaredField("mMessageView");
                mMessage.setAccessible(true);
                TextView mMessageView = (TextView) mMessage.get(mAlertController);
                mMessageView.setPadding(mMessageView.getPaddingLeft(), (int) (mMessageView.getCompoundPaddingTop() + (TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 7, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()))), mMessageView.getCompoundPaddingRight(), mMessageView.getCompoundPaddingBottom());
                mMessageView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._10sdp));
                mMessageView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.font_black2));
                mMessageView.setLineSpacing(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8f, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), 1.0f);
                mMessageView.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
                mMessageView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
  


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**For Proguard use this code**

```
# for alertDialog, to customize title and message
-keep class androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog { *; }
-keep class androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialog { *; }
```