# Material Dialog Change Text Sizes

Tags: android, material-design

I would like to customise the title, description and button font sizes for the material alert dialog made using `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` using a custom style from the `styles.xml` file. However, I am not sure how to go about creating the style. Can someone please help me out with that. TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562924/changing-font-size-into-an-alertdialog

Comment: The link you have given does not use material theme. My dialog uses material theme and hence not the same classes. I tried the solutions given for dialogs without material theming, but they did not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog dialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                .setMessage(description)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                .create();

        dialog.show();

        dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextSize(18);

        TextView textView = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setTextSize(18);
        }
```